# How to include MORE Font-awesome icons in a custom blogger template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, blogger

I have two left feet in case of coding. I have downloaded a custom blogger template which renders a few social media (Facebook, twitter etc) icons but not all (500px, behance). I have tried to figure it out on my own, but sadly haven't managed to do so yet.

here is the test blog: http://kartik1110.blogspot.in/

Everywhere on the site (Navbar, right sidebar and bottom) icon for 500px doesn't show up. How do I tackle this?

As the code is a big blogger template, I couldn't figure which snippet to paste here. Pardon my shortcomings.
Thanks in Advance.

Edit: I made a mistake in original question. The additional icons dont show up in the Custom widgets that came with the template. The icons show up on blogger pages and other widgets. Any idea which piece of code removes the ability of other icons to show up?

here is the code for right side bar 'follow me' widget, where limited icons are showing up.

```
    <b:widget id='LinkList2' locked='false' title='Follow Me' type='LinkList' version='1' visible='true'>
  <b:includable id='main'>

<b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'><h2><data:title/></h2></b:if>
 <div class='widget-content'>
   <ul class='site-social-networks secondary-2-primary style-default show-title'>
     <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
       <li><a expr:href='data:link.target' target='_blank'><i/><data:link.name/></a></li>
     </b:loop>
   </ul>
   <b:include name='quickedit'/>
 </div>
</b:includable>
```

Comment: Have you maybe plugins in your browser, such as: Ad Block (Plus), Ghostery, Disconnect, uBlock, et cetera?

Comment: the problem is universal. All broswers (Chrome, firefox, IE), On windows and mac as well as on android and iphone.

Answer (score 0):

The template already uses Font Awesome, as you mentioned. All you have to do now is to insert the icon you wish to use.

The easiest way to do this is to add the HTML element as explained [here](http://fontawesome.io/examples/). By going to "icons" inside font awesome, you can search for whatever icon you need and find the necessary HTML code you include.

For the case of [500px](http://fontawesome.io/icon/500px/) you have to include `<i class="fa fa-500px" aria-hidden="true"></i>` on your HTML and you'll add the correct icon.

You can see the result in this [image](https://i.gyazo.com/534dc91962d90f7c2a662bce38d2e5a6.png)

Just do the same with any icon you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for the work around.
All other icons show up on just adding a link in blogger 'link list gadget'.
even on the official site of the template it says, icon support for Facebook, twitter, blogloving, instagram, pinterest and flickr. I wonder What part of the code removes the rendering of other icons. if I could remove that part, life would become easier!
Once again Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your version is older, or incomplete. On the FA website they also warn that Adblock Plus removes some icons.

In any case, you can try getting the fontset directly, something I always recommend for loading speed/seo anyway. Just follow the instructions on their website:

http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Comment: The icons show up on other parts like blogger pages and other widgets. Just not in the Custom gadgets which came with the template. They also mention the supported icons as facebook, twitter, bloglovin, instagram, pinterest.. I wonder what piece of code remove the support of other icons from those custom widgets. If I could remove that code, life would become easier! Btw, Thanks for addressing the question and replying :)